# asymmetrical dual channel setup

Tags: memory, performance, dual-channel

yesterday I won for free (which has yet to come):

> 16GB GOODRAM IRDM RGB Black Edition DDR4-3600 DIMM CL18 Dual Kit   -> so 2x 8gb

And I wanted to upgrade my system with it, but since I have already a different RAM, I wanted to make sure what the risk and benefits are and what I should do.
Since I am inexperience, I wanted to gain some opinion here.
If it makes sense to mix them, I want to know in what channels/slots I should put them? If it does not, should I use the one with a higher frequency or have more GB?

I will be having 4 sticks of RAM when it arrives.

I mainly use it as a general Desktop, but most of the time it's for gaming instead of productivity.

My current setup is as following:

- Motherboard: B550 AORUS PRO (rev. 1.0)
- CPU:  AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6x 3.70GHz So.AM4 BOX
- RAM: 32 GB (2x 16384 MB) G.Skill Aegis DDR4-3200 DIMM CL16-18-18-38 Dual Kit    [currently in 2 & 4]
- GPU: Nvidia RTX 3080 FE
- PSU: 750 Watt Seasonic Focus GX Modular 80+ Gold

With kind regards,
S4

Comment: If you already have two sticks operating in dual channel then you should simply need to fill up the remaining slots with the new sticks. Your new memory will operate at the lowest maximum common speed between sticks, which *should* be 3200, but might be slower. Whether it is an improvement in system speed depends if you ever hit 32GB of memory used in your current system.

Comment: As to using 3600MHz RAM instead of 3200, it is of the order of a 10% difference in speed and only likely to be noticed under extreme conditions. It *might* translate to a few fps more in games but is likely to be difficult to quantify or even provably measure. In gaming the GPU will be doing the heavy lifting and RAM plays a part in keeping the CPU going, and is important in keeping the GPU fed with data and instructions, but a 10% increase in one component doesn't translate to a 10% increase in *everything*. The only way to know for sure is to benchmark and swap things around.